# Calculate Feature Area in Shapefile, which crs to use?

Tags: coordinate-system, area

For a global shapefile I would like to calculate the area per feature. If I understand correctly it is best practice to reproject your shapefile to a projected coordinate system. In the past I've used [World Eckert IV](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/54012/). Are there any other projections that are suitable or even better for global area calculation, ideally with an epsg code?

Comment: I've used https://epsg.io/54009 for global equal-area work.